# Custom cell is causing a 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle:

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, nib, custom-cell

I am trying to add a custom cell using a XIB file into my table and I am getting this error when I attempt to run it:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle (loaded)' with name 'parentCell''
```

These are the steps I have taken to get here:

1) Created a custom xib storyboard cell
2) Set the identifier of the storyboard cell to parentCell
3) Created a class for the custom xib as ParentTableViewCell
4) Set the class of the xib storyboard cell to ParentTableViewCell
5) Created a table view on the main storyboard and made an IBOutlet for the table in the main ViewController called itemsTable.
6) set the in the viewdidload of the main ViewController:

```
itemsTable.dataSource = self
itemsTable.delegate = self
itemsTable.register(UINib(nibName: "parentCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "parentCell")
```

7) In the cellForRowAt:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "parentCell", for: indexPath) as! ParentTableViewCell
return cell
```

Can you guys see if I missed a step that's causing the issue?

I have tried command + shift + k and its displaying the same error.

Comment: what is xib name ?

Comment: Hey @Sh_Khan the xib name is ParentTableViewCell.xib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If xib name is `ParentTableViewCell.xib` Then you should do

```
itemsTable.register(UINib(nibName: "ParentTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "parentCell")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Finally got it working.